# How to get address of an upgradeable smart contract in another smart contract

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts, contract-upgrading

I have the following two contracts

```
contract MyNFT is ERC721Upgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
  function initialize() initializer public {
    __ERC721_init_unchained("My NFT", "MNF");
    __Ownable_init_unchained();
  }
}

contract MyUSD is ERC20Upgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
  address constant ADDRESS_MYNFT = ???;
  MyNFT myNFT;
  function initialize() initializer public {
    __ERC20_init_unchained("My USD", "USD");
    __Ownable_init_unchained();
    myNFT = MyNFT(ADDRESS_MYNFT);
  }
}
```

How can I obtain the address of the implementation contract MyNFT from the proxy in the smart contract MyUSD?

Answer (score 0):

`myNFT = MyNFT(ADDRESS_MYNFT);`

`ADDRESS_MYNFT` is the address of the proxy.